# No back button should land protected page once sign out is clicked in keystone.js

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Am using the default admin UI configuration of keystonejs, and I have noticed while i have logged in to the admin UI am able to see the admin UI.
And when i clicked sign out, i have been redirected to the signing form.

This okay but when i click the back button on the browser am able to see the previous admin UI where i was been before. and my question is i don’t want to see my previous pages that are protected once i have clicked sign out i.e.  keystone should redirect to the  sign in page if the requested route is the protected one. How should i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a browser thing than a Keystone security issue. When you go to the previous page in your browser, you aren't reloading that page (most of the time). It just loads what that page looked like at the time. If you were to reload that page, you'd be locked out of the Admin UI until you log in again.